# Android open new activity in webview is not successful - shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not working

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to do an app that is mainly base on webview. MainActivity is to load www.example.com/products.php.

www.example.com/products.php - display all products*

www.example.com/products.php?id=123 - display individual product base on product ID

***www.example.com/cart.php - when clickcing on "Add to cart" on product.php?id=123, it will not open a new Activity but remain in the same activity.***

MainActivity.java

```
    private WebView wv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings wss = wv.getSettings();
    wss.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/product.php");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

}
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com/cart.php")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }else{
            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        }

    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(wv.canGoBack()){
        wv.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

And also for "shouldOverrideUrlLoading " , it shows depreciated... so what's the new name for this?

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` is depreciated now, instead use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)`

If you could elaborate your problem a bit, i might be able to help you. It's not clear to me what your problem is currently.

Comment: thx. how about my main question? any idea?